# how to limit the mysql data access based on the number of records are shown in every page of datatable

Tags: mysql, pagination, datatables, limit

I have a table that is holding almost a thousand records. Using datatables plugin I can limit the number of records shown on the screen but the data query from database takes too much time. I want to limit database query based on the number of records shown by the datatables.

Comment: have a look at datatable server side implementation, this should be a good start to get things rolling

Comment: I want to get the number of records based on the number of rows shown in every page of datatable. What it does right now is that queries the whole table and divides on every page.  For example the first page should query last 10 records from database and the second page should query the 2nd last 10 records from database.

Comment: Which version of data tables are you using?